# Zend2 read all Json files content and return results to view

Tags: php, json, zend-framework2

I have been struggling the last 2 days to make this work but I cannot get to the bottom of it. I need to read all the .json files from a folder and get back the result so I can make my "statistics" wich are stored in those .json files.

If I use print_r(); in the controller, I get arrays with the content from the files, wich is exactly what I want, but when I want to pass it to the view, I get only 1 array, and that is the first, no matter what I tried. I also tried returning with JsonModel() but no success, I get the same result.

This is the function I tried using to read the files and hopefully get back the result:

```
public function getJSONAction(){

        $my_array_data = array();

        //$reader = new \Zend\Config\Reader\Json();

        //$data   = $reader->fromFile('./data/tti/video.json');

        $files = glob('./data/stats/*.{json,txt}', GLOB_BRACE);

        foreach($files as $file) {

            //$data = array($reader->fromFile($file));

            $data  =  file_get_contents($file);

            $my_array_data = json_decode($data, TRUE);

            $view = new JsonModel ( array(

                    'my_array_data' => $my_array_data
            ));
        }

        $view->setTerminal(true);

        return $view;
    }
```

I tried many ways, but I still cannot make it work, can someone please point me to the right direction ? Or some example would be even more helpfull.

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

I got it working... it was my stupid mistake, I should have put ** $my_array_data[] **

Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: At the moment you're creating a  new array and view model in each loop iteration, which I don't think is what you were intending?

Comment: @TimFountain - yes it's true, but I am just stuck and I don't know what to do... I really need to read those files and get the values into my view...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try once like this:

```
public function getJSONAction(){

    $my_array_data = array();

    $reader = new \Zend\Config\Reader\Json();

    $files = glob('./data/stats/*.{json,txt}', GLOB_BRACE);

    foreach($files as $file) {

        $data = array($reader->fromFile($file));

        $data = file_get_contents($file);

        $my_array_data = array_merge( $my_array_data, json_decode($data, TRUE));

    }

    $view = new JsonModel ( array(

        'my_array_data' => $my_array_data
    ));

    $view->setTerminal(true);

    return $view;
}
```

The main difference is merging the different data arrays into one and then returning the merged result in a `JsonModel`.

Comment: @NorbertBoros Maybe I misunderstand your problem. What do you mean with 1 result? Can you share some details on expected result and current result?

Comment: Yeah well all along it was returning 1 array, because I should have put  $my_array_data[] when storing into the array.. a stupid lame mistake of mine, so sorry for this. Thank you anyway!